# Scale Testing Approach With Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, frameworks, load-testing, stress-testing

I was asked to design scale testing framework architecture using multi threading approach. Expectation from the framework is mentioned below

1. Spanning 10 000 requests at a time via API calls (later increase to millions of request).
2. Need to run application in clustered environment / container environment
3. Need to monitor each thread and operation status along with some metrics such as time taken to complete the task etc.

I'm new to Multi threading as well as Framework designing part, could anyone please suggest the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of free and open source load testing tools which you can either use as they are or to build your "framework" on top of them. The most popular, maintained and developed are:

- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Locust](https://locust.io/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

See [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article for more information on the above solutions. Once you figure out which one to choose you can put it into container like [LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and orchestrate containers via [Docker Swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, In our case we are not allowed to use any open source tools, Hence need some idea on building framework for the scale test across clusters with monitoring options.